# Can OS X Lion Server send an email when a user connects via SSH or VPN?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I'd like OS X Lion Server to send me an email alert whenever a user attempts to connect or establishes a successful connection to it via SSH or VPN or any other service.

The only email alerts OS X Lion Server can send are:

- disk space
- software updates
- certificate expiration

Does anyone know how to make this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script and save it in /etc/sshrc

```
#!/bin/bash

ADDRESS="your_email@example.com"

IP=`echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d " " -f 1`
DATE=`date`

echo "User $USER just logged in from $IP at $DATE" | mail -s "ssh login alert" "$ADDRESS"
```

This will work using the default sshd settings in Mavericks.  In order to avoid SPAM filters, once I get the first message in gmail, I mark it as important and add the sender to my address book.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a process that tailed the ssh log at least, and kicked off an email with each appropriate entry.

something like:

#!/bin/bash
tail -f /var/log/secure.log | grep 'session opened for user' | mail -s "Server login event" "myemail@example.com"

A quick test, at least on Linux, shows it works.  YMMV, you may have to adjust the grep for the appropriate pattern, and the usual caveats with email from random servers apply - check the mail log to see if went out, and of course, you'll need an MTA of some kind running.  Don't be surprised if the email is rejected by the recipient MTA for about a dozen reasons.

If you need anything more sophisticated there are programs that do this kind of thing.  I believe portsentry at least at one time was popular.  You could crudely emulate it with tcpdump too if you are in a hurry.

Comment: I don't think I have an MTA. I tried setting up postfix, but Gmail rejected my email, because it's not authenticating, even though I told it to use STL. How does Mail.app do this without the MTA?